# Make method accessible only to other class

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I have two classes, `Sensor` and `Channel`. They are used by "plugging" a sensor in a channel (that is, setting the `Sensor` property of `Channel` with a `Sensor` instance). Then, when you call `AddSamples` in a `Channel` with a non-null Sensor, subscribers of `Sensor.WhenNewSamples` would be notified:

```
public abstract class Channel
{
    public Sensor Sensor { get; set; }

    public abstract void AddSamples(IEnumerable<double> samples)
}

public abstract class Sensor
{
    public abstract IObservable<double> WhenNewSamples { get; }

    internal abstract void AddSamples(IEnumerable<double> samples);
}
```

What I would like to achieve is a way to pass those samples internally, without having to create an exposed `Sensor.AddSamples`. Also, of course, it should work with subclasses defined in other assemblies, since `Sensor` and `Channel` are abstract, and defined in the domain model library.

UPDATE:

The following implementation would be fine, but it doesn't compile because `Sensor.AddSamples` is internal and the derived classes are in other assemblies:

```
public class ConcreteChannel : Channel
{
    public override void AddSamples(IEnumerable<double> samples)
    {
        // AddSamples below is inaccessible
        Sensor.AddSamples(samples);
    }
}

public class ConcreteSensor : Sensor
{
    Subject<double> _subject = new Subject<double>();

    public override IObservable<double> WhenNewSamples
    {
        get { return _subject.AsObservable(); }
    }

    // "No suitable method found to override"
    internal override void AddSamples(IEnumerable<double> samples)
    {
        samples.ToList().ForEach(s => _subject.OnNext(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: Make `AddSamples` protected? Then it´s only visible to deriving classes. Or did I understand you whrong?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I want `Channel.AddSamples` to be public, but I don't know how to encapsulate the passing of data from `Channel` to `Channel.Sensor` whithout creating a public `Sensor.AddSamples`, which I would like to avoid. I am looking for a sort of "magic tunnel" where I can only add samples in one class, and it will pop out at the other, provided that they are "connected" to each other (that is, `Channel.Sensor` property is set to an instance of `Sensor`). See my update.

Comment: If you need access to a member from outside the class and the assembly then it should be `public`. No way around this.

Comment: Did you try declaring AddSamples as "protected internal" ? you can inherit it in subclasses created even in another assembly.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya This still won´t provide access to that member from within `ConcreteChannel`.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, but I still can't access `Channel.Sensor.AddSamples` from `Channel`...

Answer (score 1):

I have figured that I was delegating too much implementation details to subclasses, so one possible solution would be to use the Template Method design pattern, using three different methods in cooperation:

- One is the *template method*: a protected abstract method that should be fleshed out by the subclasses;
- Other is an internal non-virtual method implementing the "business logic": a *call* to the protected template method from an internal one;
- A public method in some "outer" class, forwarding the call to the internal method in the "inner" class.

That way, I get the following call stack:

1. I call a public method in the outer subclass defined in client assembly;
2. That method is actually implemented in the base class in core assembly, and calls the internal method from the inner base class also in core assembly;
3. The internal method in client base class calls the protected template method, which is implemented by inner subclass in client assembly.

I tested and it works, so here are teh codez:

Core assembly:

```
public abstract class Channel
{
    // inner class is a property of outer class
    public Sensor Sensor { get; set; }

    // Public method in outer class calls internal method in inner class
    public void AddSamples(IEnumerable<double> samples)
    {
        Sensor?.AddSamplesInternal(samples);
    }
}

public abstract class Sensor
{
    // domain specific property exposing the effects of template method
    public abstract IObservable<double> WhenNewSamples { get; }

    // internal method forwards the call to a protected abstract "template" method
    internal void AddSamplesInternal(IEnumerable<double> samples)
    {
        AddSamplesProtected(samples);
    }

    // protected abstract method to be implemented by subclasses
    protected abstract void AddSamplesProtected(IEnumerable<double> samples);
}
```

Client assembly:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

public class ConcreteChannel : Channel
{
    // no need to do anything - public method defined in base class
}

public class ConcreteSensor : Sensor
{
    // domain specific implementation
    public override IObservable<double> WhenNewSamples
    {
        get { return _subject.AsObservable(); }
    }
    Subject<double> _subject = new Subject<double>();

    // template method implemented locally, but called from business logic present in core lib
    protected override void AddSamplesProtected(IEnumerable<double> samples)
    {
        samples.ToList().ForEach(sample => _subject.OnNext(sample));
    }
}
```

Sample program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConcreteChannel channel = new ConcreteChannel();
        ConcreteSensor sensor = new ConcreteSensor();

        // "plugging" a sensor into a channel
        channel.Sensor = sensor;

        // "sensor" works as a data source for other client code
        sensor.WhenNewSamples.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        // channel works as a data target for data coming from some server class
        channel.AddSamples(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(Convert.ToDouble));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ability of nested classes to access private/protected members of *parent* class:

```
abstract class A
{
    protected abstract void SomeMethod();
}
abstract class B { }

class AA : A
{
    public class BB : B
    {
        public void Test(AA a) => a.SomeMethod(); // no problem to access it here
    }
    protected override void SomeMethod() { } // is not public
}
```

Comment: If I understand right, this would invert the containment relationship. For example, if I want BB to access AA.Method, then BB would need to be inside AA? Because currently I have AA being a property of BB. I'm a bit confused (although I am going to try it now).